# Is the React Context feature essentially a view model?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm giving the react context api a look, I decided to try setting it up to handle a login popup window:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export const LoginContext = React.createContext();

import firebase from 'firebase';

export class LoginProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        loginOpen: false,
        user: Object
    }
    render() {
        return <LoginContext.Provider value={{
            state: this.state,
            showLogin: () => this.setState({
                loginOpen: true
            }),
            closeLogin: () => this.setState({
                loginOpen: false
            }),
            login: async (username, password) => {
                var auth = firebase.auth();
                try {
                    var that = this;
                    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).then((user)=>{
                        that.setState({user: user, loginOpen: false});
                    });
                }
                catch (E) {
                    return E;
                }
            }
        }}>
            {this.props.children}
        </LoginContext.Provider>;
    }
}
```

Used within a React component with the relevant functions being called.

It occurred to me that LoginProvider is a view model.

Which makes me wonder: Am I using the context feature correctly? Was this its intended usage?

If so why is the usage so archaic? What benefits does it provide? I mean it's less code than going through redux or sagas but still unnecessarily cumbersome.

Comment: I agree the process of extracting the context.state is cumbersome, especially needing to wrap multiple context calls in a `<React.fragment>`, but I've started storing all of my primary functions in the top-level functions and attaching them to the context through the state like `this.state = {
handleSubmit: this.handleSubmit.bind (this)}`. I may be using it incorrectly as well, but I've found it to be advantageous.

Comment: I'm in the process of building a Vigenere cipher that uses Context so I could learn more about it. I plan on adding what I've done to my JSFiddle, so I can send you a link to see how I've managed to make that work if you're interested.

Comment: If, by the view model you mean a class containing the data to be displayed later on, then yes - context can be used as such. Basically, context holds a global state, you can use it however you like. Is it cumbersome? Not really, since you use context to deal with the data that when changed, should be reflected somewhere. If you don't need that, simply use a singleton class.